# Can't delete form database SQLGrammarException

Tags: mysql, hibernate, crud

I want to DELETE column from base in hibernate where my inserted -regBroj- parameter  is same as one in a base.

This is my method in controller for deleting.But i constantly get
SQLGrammarException:
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'BG026CH' in 'where clause'

This 'BG026CH' is value of regBroj that i use as a parameter to find vehicle in database and delete it.And i insert it in text area in adminPage.

```
  public String izbrisi(String regBroj) {
     List<Vozilo> lista = listaj();
        Session s = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            if (regBroj .equals(lista.get(i).getRegBroj())) {
                String izbrisiquery = "DELETE FROM Korisnik WHERE brojLk=" + regBroj + "";
                Query q = s.createQuery(izbrisiquery);
                int a = q.executeUpdate();
                t.commit();
                return "adminPage";
            }
        }
        t.commit();
        return "error";


    }
```

Comment: The answer given by @Dhaval below should fix your immediate problem, but you should _seriously_ consider using prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

Please replace below string with these one

```
String izbrisiquery = "DELETE FROM Korisnik WHERE brojLk='" + regBroj + "'";
```

Comment: Great it works i have forgotten to add -'   '- inside my query .

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using prepared statements because they will automatically take care of escaping field values with quotes, and they will also protect you from SQL injection.

```
// obtain a Connection object using your Hibernate session, or through some other means
Connection conn = getDBConnection();

for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
    if (regBroj .equals(lista.get(i).getRegBroj())) {
        String izbrisiquery = "DELETE FROM Korisnik WHERE brojLk = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(izbrisiquery);
        ps.setString(1, regBroj);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        t.commit();

        return "adminPage";
    }
}
```

To see how SQL injection works, or how a malicious user could wreck the `Korisnik` table, imagine that someone hacks the UI to pass a value of `'' OR TRUE` for `brojLK`.  This is what the resulting `DELETE` statement would look like:

```
DELETE FROM Korisnik WHERE brojLk = '' OR TRUE
```

In other words, this injected query would drop your entire table!  Prepared statements would choke on this input and a hacker would not get as far as executing the query.

Comment: This might be a stupid question.Do you know some good tutorials on prepared statement

Comment: Start with [MKYong](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/), who usually does a good job of explaining things.

Comment: @Stanimir Apart that, prepared statements are more suitable to cache it.